# Spanning set and dimension of a vector space over some field

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Can someone explain how it is possible to have the number of elements in a spanning set, $S$, be greater than the dimension of a vector space  $V / \mathbb{F}$?

$\#S$ $\ge$ $dim(V)$

Comment: Yes of course; recall that a spanning set of some vector space is not required to be linearly independent. For example, the set $\{ 1, 2 \}$ spans the vector space $\Bbb{R}$ over the field $\Bbb{R}$; but the cardinality of $\{ 1, 2 \}$ is $2 > 1 = \dim \Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Ahh, okay. I suppose I was overthinking it - doesn't have to be linearly independent, thank you.

Comment: It is however true, for finite dimensional vector spaces, that if the number of vectors in a spanning set is the same as the dimension of the vector space, the set is independent.

Comment: In a rather extreme example, take $S=V$. Then $S$ is certainly a spanning set, but not a very interesting one.

Comment: @physicsmajor No problem. I would say you might not overthink it. Math is simple (I am not saying it is easy :)); to solve a conceptual problem like this it almost suffices to check the relevant definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way:

Given a basis $S$ for a vector space $V$, add the zero vector to S. If so, every vector in V can still be written as a linear combination of the vectors in S ($c_k\times0 = 0)$, but S isn't a basis anymore, it is a spanning set.

The same could be said if you added linear combinations of those vectors or scalar multiples of the vectors in S (in this case, just take $c_k =0$ for those vectors that constitute "repetitions").